# Refactoring React Component to ES6. Getting error in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, reactjs

I have refactored the following component to ES6 and I am using the latest version of BabelJS.  When I run webpack everything compiles with no issues the problems is I am getting the following error in the console In

Firefox 42.0 i get the following Error

```
    mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial 
[[Prototype]] value using Object.create bundle.js:19697:416
    TypeError: _react2.default.propTypes is undefined
```

In Google Chrome the following error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined
```

Here is the following component I am not sure what I am missing or what I have done wrong.  I have been troubleshooting this for the last few days now.

```
import React from "react";
var $ = require('jquery');

class ChatList extends React.Component{

  getInitialState(){
    return{
      chat:[]
    }
  }


  getChats (){
    $ajax({
      url: this.props.URL,
      type:'GET',
      beforeSend: function(request){
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id","AppID");
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key","AppKEY");
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
      },
      error: function(data){
        console.log('There was an error in getting the chats');
      },
      success:function(data){
        if(this.isMounted()){
          this.setState({
            chats: data.results
          });
        }
      }.bind(this)
    })
  }

  ComponentDidMount (){
    this.interval = setInterval(function(){
      this.getCharts();
    }.bind(this),1000)
  }

  ComponentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  render(){

    var list = this.state.chats.map((item,index)=>{
        return <li className = "list-group-item" key={item.objectId}> {item.text} </li>
    })

    return (
      <ul className="list-group">
        {list}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

ChatList.PropTypes = {
  URL: props.string.isRequired
};

ChatList.defaultProps = {
  URL: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chat/'
};


export default ChatList;
```

Answer (score 2):

A few issues I noticed, which hopefully solves this issue.

1. Since you are using ES6 class to define React components, `getInitialState` [cannot be used like that](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes). Instead you should have:

   ```
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { chat: [] };
   }
   ```
2. You have `ChatList.PropTypes = …` instead it should be `ChatList.propTypes` (small `p`) and `props` is undefined, hence your error about 'cannot access property string of undefined'

   ```
   ChatList.propTypes = {
       URL: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
   };
   ```

Comment: I made modifications to the original code with the new suggestions above but the console throws the following error.

TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Comment: Which version of React are you using? If possible, can you upgrade to the latest version ??

Comment: I am using React 0.14.2 and ReactDOM v0.14.2. I am also using the latest version of BabelJS

Comment: I solved the problem.  I deleted all my Node modules reinstalled react react-dom everything worked.  Thanks everybody for all the help

Comment: @stargatesg1 that's good to hear, I suspect that although your package.json said 14.2, you still had an older version of react in the node_modules causing the error you saw about "Super expression", deleting and reinstalling ensured you are in the latest version.

Comment: Are you kidding me? `propTypes` in one place but `PropTypes` in another? What is this, PHP? (thank you a lot @luanped )

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the `props` variable anywhere, as this appears to be your issue? React prop types are available on `React.PropTypes`.

Can you try this:

```
ChatList.PropTypes = {
  URL: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```